# Is there any free C test code coverage tool for Windows?

Tags: c, testing, code-coverage

Please let me know if there are any free C test code coverage tool for Windows environment

Comment: if c# ncover, if c change the tag

Comment: you are probably looking for microsoft visual C express edition

Comment: You mention C in your text, but tagged your question `c#` - which one is correct?

Comment: @Moonlight: MS Visual C express is free, true, but doe it have test coverage capabilities?  I thought that was only available in the high end editions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

[gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) is widely used as a test coverage tool for C.

Being part of the gcc family, I'm pretty sure it works under windows.

Whether it works with "Windows" C code in another matter; Windows C isn't
the same as GCC C.  Close, but no cigar.   I don't know of any free
Windows C test coverage tools.

My company provides  [commercial test coverage tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage) for many languages, including GCC C and C++, as well as Microsoft C and C++.